# save a zip file downloaded in AWS EC2 to a gzip file in S3, using python boto3 in memory

Tags: python, zip, boto3, gzip

I appreciate this question is quite specific, but I believe it should be a common problem. I've solved parts of it but not the entire chain.

**Input**:
in AWS EC2 instance, I download a *zip-compressed* file from the internet

**Output**:
I save the *gzip-compressed* file to an S3 bucket

I see 2 ways of doing this:

1. saving temporary files in EC2, and then copying them to S3
2. converting the data in memory in EC2, and saving directly to S3

I know how to do the first option, but because of resource constraints, and because I need to download a lot of files, I would like to try the second option. This is what I have so far:

```
import requests, boto3, gzip

zip_data = requests.get(url).content

#I can save a temp zip file in EC2 like this, but I would like to avoid it
with open(zip_temp, 'wb') as w:    
    w.write(zip_data)

#missing line that decompresses the zipped file in memory and returns a byte-object, I think?
#like: data = SOMETHING (zip_data)

gz_data = gzip.compress(data)

client = boto3.client('s3')
output = client.put_object( 
        Bucket = 'my-bucket',
        Body = gz_data,
        Key = filename)
```

Besides, are there any general considerations I should think about when deciding which option to go for?

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was quite simple:

```
import requests, boto3, gzip
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO

zip_data = requests.get(url).content

with ZipFile(BytesIO(zip_data)) as myzip:

    with myzip.open('zip_file_inside.csv') as mycsv:

        gz_data = gzip.compress(mycsv.read())

        client = boto3.client('s3')

        output = client.put_object( 
            Bucket = 'my-bucket',
            Body = gz_data,
            Key = filename)
```